# LocalDate within EntityClass upsets sonarQube

Tags: java, jpa, java-8, sonarqube, localdate

I have Entity Class with LocalDate in it and Entity Class it-self implements serializable as per the JPA specifications.

Everything is up untill now, but SonarQube now complains the:

```
Local Date is a Value type Class and should not be serialized.
```

It suggests to either remove the field or make it transient - both of which wont work in this case as we need those fields to be persisted to the database or maybe some in-memory storage.

```
public class User implements Serializable{
    //other attributes

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_DATE")
    private LocalDate updatedDate;

}
```

Could anyone please suggest how can we work around this?

Thanks

Comment: You should add some of the code in question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe have added the entity class, where sonar don't like the usage of LocalDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the documentation,
https://sonarcloud.io/coding_rules?open=squid%3AS3437&rule_key=squid%3AS3437

You can either put `transient` in front of the `date` field 
or you can suppress the warning like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("squid:S3437") //LocalDate is serializable
public class User implements Serializable{..}
```